# Get a status code from HttpRequestException with netstandard 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I'm having trouble to get a status code from a `HttpRequestException` on netstandard 2.1 at the catch block. At the .NET Framework there is an extra property "StatusCode", but I can't find any similar for netstandard. Is there any alternative?

Thanks in advance.

I already tried to convert a `HttpRequestException` into a `WebException`. Catching a `WebException` does not trigger the catch.

Comment: Available for Net 5+ so you need to target at least that to get the Status code. Maybe this helps you deciding what to target https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1#when-to-target-net50-or-net60-vs-netstandard

Comment: I would target net 5+ with pleasure, but it's in a library for ASP.NET Core and Xamarin (netstandard)

Comment: Do you get that exception from your own call to `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`? Then rolling your own version of that method would be an option throwing a derived HttpRequestException with the additional StatusCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments to your OP, the `StatusCode` property was introduced in .NET 5 and won't be available in .NetStandard. This means you have to "do it yourself".

You can include the status code value in the existing exception without having to create and maintain a new exception type by leveraging the `Data` dictionary like this (change the names to your liking):

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    public static void MyEnsureSuccessStatusCode(this HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.SetStatusCode(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode))
        {
            // Intentionally left empty. Will never be reached.
        }
    }
}

public static class HttpRequestExceptionExtensions
{
    private const string StatusCodeKeyName = "StatusCode";

    public static bool SetStatusCode(this HttpRequestException httpRequestException, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        httpRequestException.Data[StatusCodeKeyName] = httpStatusCode;

        return false;
    }

    public static HttpStatusCode? GetStatusCode(this HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
    {
        return (HttpStatusCode?)httpRequestException.Data[StatusCodeKeyName];
    }
}
```

Note the usage of an *always-false exception filter* there. This ensures modifying the original exception doesn't incur severe costs as it retains the original exception as is (it is never "caught" there)

You can then use the new extension instead of the original `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` to throw the exception:

```
// grab real response here
var response = default(HttpResponseMessage);
response.MyEnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

And you can grab the status code from the exception object using the `GetStatusCode` extension on whoever is catching the exception upstream.

If you want to make this even more robust, and ensure that you only call `GetStatusCode` on an exception that was thrown using the custom overload, you can also add a "marker" value in the dictionary to indicate that it was thrown using the extension and act on that (for example, throw an `InvalidOperationException` saying the method can only be used in conjunction with `MyEnsureSuccessStatusCode`).

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm! I only had to put the GetStringAsync in a try & catch (empty) to ignore the default exception.